# Create accordions into accordions

Tags: javascript, css, accordion, panel

I have some requests because i have trouble with accordion and panel. I would like that my accordion contain other accordion. But i have have some trouble with the size of my mainpage because the div did not align under each other. Otherwise, in my job we can't use js so i would like code only in html and css.

I post my code :
HTML :

```
<button class = "accordion">Fat Section</button>

<div class = "panel">
<button class = "accordion"</button>
<div class='panel'>
<p>Statut:</p>
</div>
</div>

    button.accordion {
    background-color:#ADD8E6;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    display: block;}

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #B0E0E6;

    div.panel {
    padding: 0 18 px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:white;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display:none;} 


   div.accordion
  {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
  }
  button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  margin-left: 85%;}

  button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: why the php tag? there's also hardly enough code for an accordion. This sounds like a "can you help me finish this?" question.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("ul.trackAccordion").accordion({
   collapsible: true,
   active: false,
   heightStyle: "content"
  });
});
```

```css
input:focus { outline: none; }

body,html{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/crossword.png');
 background-repeat: repeat;
}

a {
 color: white;
 outline: none !important;
}

a:-webkit-any-link{
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0 !important;
 }

.trackAccordion{
 margin: 50px auto;
 background-color: #2d2d2d;
 height: 790px;
 width: 296px;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Helvetica';
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top: 30px;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

ul.trackAccordion > li{
 color: white;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 border-bottom: thick solid #464646;
}

ul.tracks > li{
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #444444;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 14px;

}

ul#cert_Track > li{
 border-left:thick solid #01cfe7;
 border-left-width:20px;
}

ul#kids_Track > li{
 border-left:thick solid #aa2e54;
 border-left-width:20px;
}

ul#more_Track > li{
 border-left:thick solid #618daa;
 border-left-width:20px;
}


.proTrack{
 padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.accoTrack{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.blueBorder{
 background: #00d0e7;
 position: relative;
 left: -58px;
 padding: 20px 13px 19px 7px;
}

.nestedElemAccor{
 margin-top: -20px;
}
.nestedElems{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.begNestElem{
 background-color: #0bddf0;
 padding: 13px 105px 13px 105px
}

.intNestElem{
 background-color: #08a2b0;
 padding: 13px 105px 13px 105px
}

.advNestElem{
 background-color: #067983;
 padding: 13px 105px 13px 105px
}
.trackAccordion {
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: 790px;    //Check by commenting the height.
  width: 296px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <body>
<ul class = "trackAccordion">
 

 <a href="#">INDIVIDUAL CLASSES</a>
 <ul class = "course_beginner trackAccordion nestedElemAccor"> 
  
   <li class = "nestedElems">
    <a href="#" class="begNestElem">BEGINNER</a> 
     <ul class="tracks">
     <li>Intro to DJing (DJ 101)</li>
     <li>Intensive Beginners (DJ INT)</li>
     <li>Intensive Beginners (DJ INT)</li>
     </ul>
   </li>

   <li class = "nestedElems"> 
   <a href="#" class="intNestElem">INTERMEDIATE</a>
     <ul class="tracks">
     <li>Mixing (M 202)</li>
     <li>Scratching (S 202)</li>
     <li>Music Production II (MP 202)</li>
     </ul>
   </li>

   <li class = "nestedElems">
     <a href="#" class="advNestElem">ADVANCED</a> 
     <ul class="tracks">
     <li>Mixing III (M 303)</li>
     <li>Mixing IV (M 404)</li>
     <li>Mixing V (M 505)</li>
     <li>Scratching III (S 303) </li>
     <li>Battle DJing (S 404)</li>
     <li>Music Production III (MP 303)</li>
     <li>Music Production IV (MP 404)</li>
     <li>Master Class - Team Routines</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  
 </ul>
 </li> <!-- END element which hold Individual class in accordian -->

 
 <a href="#">MORE OPTIONS</a> 
 <ul class = "tracks" id = "more_Track">
 <li>Private Lessons</li>
 <li>Group Events</li>
 <li>Workshops</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        
</body>
```

Its different from your code but you can find a suggestions from it